# Ubuntu 13.4 doesn't search for files on desktop when type a letter

Tags: 13.04, search

When I trigger show desktop action and get a clear view of the desktop, I want to do fast search for some file eg. If file name is "myname", I will type first letter "m" and file should be selected.

All version of Ubuntu did work like that but not 13.4.

How to get back that old good search?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.4 on my Tooshiba Satellite laptop.   All you need to do is go to the Dash and type in the name of the file or folder.  It just worked for me minutes ago.